# AngularJS 2.2.4 custom validator with regexp

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, typescript

Here is the problem,

I try to build a "custom validator" for a password and an email field with angularJS v2.
Following the "standard structure", I do have these files interacting together :

```
/forms/form.component.ts
/validators/password.validator.ts
/validators/email.validator.ts
```

In my form component template, I come to this for the two concerned fields :

```
//...
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" [formControl]="passwordCtrl" required />
<div *ngIf="passwordCtrl.dirty && passwordCtrl.hasError('validPassword')">PASSWORD NOT VALID</div>
//...
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" [formControl]="emailCtrl" required />
<div *ngIf="emailCtrl.dirty && emailCtrl.hasError('validemail')">EMAIL NOT VALID</div>
//...
```

And, in the component (.ts) I have this :

```
//...
import { validateEmail } from '../validators/email.validator';
import { validatePassword } from '../validators/password.validator';
//...in constructor(fb: FormBuilder) : 
this.passwordCtrl = fb.control(this.user.password, Validators.compose([validatePassword])),
this.emailCtrl = fb.control(this.user.email, Validators.compose([validateEmail])),
//...
```

Declarations and instanciations are right in my component.ts since when I do add a "required" validator in the "compose." part, this works fine. Problem seems to come from the validator itself... Here are them :

```
//email.validator.ts
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function validateEmail(c: FormControl){
    let EMAIL_REGEXP = new RegExp(`([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+")@[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(\.[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)+`);
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
        validateEmail: {
            validemail: false
        }
    };
}

//password.validator.ts
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function validatePassword(c: FormControl) {
    let PASSWORD_REGEXP = new RegExp(`^.*(?=.{6,20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$`);
    return PASSWORD_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
        validatePassword: {
            validpassword: false
        }
    };
}
```

The validator "example" comes from there : http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

This changes nothing when I change "validpassword" or "validemail" return value (true, false, whatever). The div depending on validateemail, validatepassword validators, NEVER appears...

Thanks for reading/help

---

**Update 1 :**

My form is there to handle LOGIN and REGISTER possibilities.
So, there are 2 forms, one shows by default, another one shows when clicking on "register" link. BUT they are located on same page.

In my form.component.ts, I do create 2 formGroups :

```
//...
this.loginForm = fb.group({
    login: this.loginCtrl,
    password: this.passwordCtrl
}),
this.registerForm = fb.group({
    login: this.loginCtrl,
    password: this.passwordCtrl,
    email: this.emailCtrl
});
```

So, the two different forms, are related to specific formGroups. I bind them in the template like this (and add buttons to submit) :

```
//...
<form (ngSubmit)="register()" [formGroup]="registerForm">
//...
<button class="btn btn-default submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">Submit</button>
//...
//...
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
//...
<button class="btn btn-default submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
```

Both buttons keep disabled EXCEPT when ALL fields are completed. Meaning that : if the email field is empty in the "registerForm" group, then the "login button" in the "loginForm" group keeps disabled!

FormGroup"ing" isn't supposed to handle these cases?

Comment: Try instead hasError('validemail') this: hasError('validateEmail') - this is the property of error object that you return from validator

Comment: I wish I could hide... like forever ! :P Thanks! it works like this. And I noticed that my password regexp is wrong...

Comment: @ZasypinN.V. Updated question with related issue... :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've undestood question correctly. As I understand FormGroup only defines object of your form, and it's not responsible for showing/hiding elements of it.

Comment: Well, I'm quite confused with it... In my template, I declare that the button has to enable on condition "loginForm.valid" OR "registerForm.valid". When "registerForm" is valid, then button is clickable. If not, it's disabled. But, it only works when both 3 fields are valid. "button in login form" should be clickable when login and password are valid, email is there not required... (only required in registerform formgroup) @ZasypinN.V.

Comment: I think your email field is not valid due to other validations. Here's example I've made [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPPGWI9ACAhj1CDDLfJ0?p=preview), there ara 2 field in form. First one is required, the second one is not. Button get enabled after input in first field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130485/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-zasypin-n-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main question - instead `hasError('validemail')` use this: `hasError('validateEmail')` - this is the property of error object that you return from validator.

Update 1: use for your form components new instances of FormControl.

```
this.loginFormLoginCtrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.loginFormPasswordCtrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.registerFormLoginCtrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.registerFormPasswordCtrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.registerFormLoginCtrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    ....
this.loginForm = fb.group({
     login: this.loginFormLoginCtrl,
     password: this.loginFormPasswordCtrl
});
this.registerForm = fb.group({
     login: this.registerFormLoginCtrl,
     password: this.registerFormPasswordCtrl,
     email: this.registerFormEmailCtrl
});
```